# Converse implication logic using exponentiation operator in ES7?

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, short-circuiting, ecmascript-2016

Per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33866478/3011380), we know

```
console.log(false ** false == true);  // true
console.log(false ** true == false);  // true
console.log(true ** false == true);  // true
console.log(true ** true == true);  // true
```

I think we can implement [Converse implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_implication) through `exponentiation operator` in ES7.

Given the return value of function `f()` and `g()` are `boolean`. So we can use this simple codes

```
if (g() ** f()) { 
   // 
}
```

to replace

```
if ((g() && f()) || !f()) {
    //
}
```

Some test codes are [here](http://babeljs.io/repl/). Is it valid or not under ES7?

Comment: Even if it's valid, what's the meaning to use that? I can't see that it make the expression more efficient, nor clearer.

Comment: Use `g() || !f()` instead, it's much more readable. Try: `[[false, false], [false, true], [true, false], [true, true]].map(function(a) { return a[0] || !a[1]; })`

Answer (score 2):

The statement:

```
if ((g() && f()) || !f()) {
```

Has several potentially bad implications, resulting from the short-circuit mechanism:

1. if `g()` is falsy, `f()` is evaluated once, and the negated result is used to branch.
2. if `g()` is truthy, and **the first** `f()` is also truthy, the content of the `if` block is evaluated.
3. if `g()` is truthy, and **the first** `f()` is falsy, `f()` is evaluated again - which might be a costly operation and might return a completely different value, which is then negated and used to branch.

The statement:

```
if (g() ** f())
```

results in both functions evaluated exactly once, and the results are then logically combined to branch.

Depending on required side effects and / or evaluation order, you should either use:

```
let gVal = g(), fVal = f();
if(gVal || !fVal) { ... }
```

Or

```
if(g() || !f()) { ... }
```

---

Having said all that, to answer the question itself... ECMAScript 2016 is not finalized yet, but your assumptions seem correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Exponentiation can be used for converse implication in ES6.

You can verify this [here](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20a%20%3D%20true%20%3B%0Avar%20b%20%3D%20false%3B%0A%0A%0A%0Aif(a%20**%20b)%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%221%22)%3B%0A%7D%0Aif(b%20**%20a)%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%222%22)%3B%0A%7D%0Aif(a%20**%20a)%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%223%22)%3B%0A%7D%0Aif(b%20**%20b)%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%224%22)%3B%0A%7D)